# How to solve this (null): error: CFBundleIdentifier 'com.abcd.efg.*' contains illegal character '*'?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, cfbundleidentifier

I have an App Id like this 'com.abcd.efg.*'. I have entered the correct app id in Bundle Identifier from .plist file of my project. When i build my project below error message is displaying.

```
(null): error: CFBundleIdentifier 'com.abcd.efg.*' contains illegal character '*'
```

How can i run the project with using this app id? Can anyone please guide me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

esteric * is not a valid character for bundle identifier, i think your giving this as you have made the provisioning profile like this. but remember, making a provisioning profile like this '*' means it will be valid for all apps containing com.xxxx.xxx.. so here you must have to select a name like com.xxxx.xxx.myTestApp or com.xxxx.xxxx.theNewApp etc

Comment: Thank you The Sadd. Dont mistaken me can you please edit your answer mentioned com.i$$$$$.i$$. to com.abcd.efg.*. Please do it for me. I got the app id from my client they have shared the provisioning profile there itself they mentioned 'com.abcd.efg.*'. So i have used in our project also. May i give my own name in the bundle identifier like 'com.abcd.efg.gopiTesting'. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes sure, you can give any name, the main idea is that it must be unique id in all your own apps plus it should be complex, i.e. can't be guess able by any one, now matter what you give, your name, your company name whatever, n i've edited that

Comment: Thank you so much The Sadd. Thank a lot for edit the answer. I will try it and let you know the result. Thanks once again.

Comment: Thank you The Sadd. I have solved the issue with your great help. Thanks once again.

Comment: o comm on dear. don't make me guilty saying again n again this thanx